# Echo statement rendering html code in output

Tags: php

This is such a basic question that I feel embarrassed asking it. Whenever I echo html tags, instead of rendering the tag, it just displays in the echo output. I have tried single and double quotes, but still no luck. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

```
<a style="margin-left: 12px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo "Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection"; ?>">Help</a>
```

ff rendered output:

```
title="Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection"
```

Comment: Do you mean that it includes `<?php` in the source code? It sounds like you're not going through your PHP interpreter. If PHP is actually installed you've most likely named your page `.html` instead of `.php`. Could you post an example on [eval.in](http://www.eval.in) or [codepad.org](http://www.codepad.org)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Echoing HTML while incorporating PHP?

Comment: Could you please paste the output so that we can see what actually is happening and if it is the expected result or not. The things that you have posted is the output or your code ??

Comment: This is what is being rendered in ff view source. title="Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection" You can see that the <br /> is being output with the echo.

Comment: @adam I am trying to use html tags in php echo. thanks

Comment: @h2 it is interpreting the php but not the html tags in echo. thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML code can not be put inside a title tag as browser will not render titles as anything else than a pure text string.

Comment: Thanks Ole. However, all I am trying to do, is to use a <br /> to seperate the lines. thanks

Comment: Oh, okay. I misunderstood you then. You cannot render html code in the title tag.

Comment: Is that even if using php within the title? because I am sure I have used $var before in title with html formatting. Thanks

Comment: PHP is a script that is run server side, before HTML is sent to the visitors browser, where the HMTL code then is rendered. So you can use php wherever you like on your website. That being within html tags or not. The only point is, that browser will not render html code within a title tag. All PHP does here is input some value to the tag, before the browser have recieved it. For all the visitors browser knows, this could be a static html file.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead for your `<a/>` tag:

```
<a style="margin-left: 12px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="<?php echo 'Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection';?>">Help</a>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<?php 
$titleText =  'Please select your boxes from the list. You can select a max of 20 boxes per submission.<br />You can select multiple boxes by holding the left ctrl on your keyboard and making your selection';
?>

<a style="margin-left: 12px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="tooltip" title="<?=$titleText;?>">Help</a>
```

Comment: Thanks adam, but still outputting the same result.

Comment: Then it is a problem with your setup, not your code. Is the code contained in a file with `.php` extension?

Comment: It is definately a .php file. All php code runs in the file except this code. I think Ole may have supplied the answer.Thanks